# How to use itertools to generate dictionaries of all permutations of a given dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, permutation, python-itertools

I have the following dictionary:

```
test = OrderedDict({
        "one":1,
        "two":2,
        "three":3
})
```

And I wish to have the following result:

```
{'three':3, 'two':2, 'one':1}
{'three':3, 'one':1, 'two':2}
{'two':2, 'three', 'one':1}
{'two':2, 'one':1, 'three':3}
{'one':1, 'three':3, 'two':2}
{'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}
```

These are all the dictionaries that can be generated using permutations on the given test dict.

For now I can only get tuples of possible permutations using the following:

```
for perm in itertools.permutations(test):
    print(perm)
```

Will output:

```
('three', 'two', 'one')
('three', 'one', 'two')
('two', 'three', 'one')
('two', 'one', 'three')
('one', 'three', 'two')
('one', 'two', 'three')
```

How can I use itertools to get dictionaries with the key/values instead of tuples ?

EDIT:
Changed test to be an OrderedDict

Comment: Dicts don't have any order, so that is impossible unless you use an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Dictionaries **do not have order**; your output 'variations' are all the same dictionary value.

Comment: Yes but the same result happens with an ordereddict

Comment: @LT: you can turn the permutations into `OrderedDict` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although dictionaries have no order you can obtain the permutations as tuple and turn those into `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import collections
>>> for item in itertools.permutations(test.items()):
...     print collections.OrderedDict(item)
...
OrderedDict([('three', 3), ('two', 2), ('one', 1)])
OrderedDict([('three', 3), ('one', 1), ('two', 2)])
OrderedDict([('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('one', 1)])
OrderedDict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
OrderedDict([('one', 1), ('three', 3), ('two', 2)])
OrderedDict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])
```

Comment: @LT: alright, I'm glad it was useful. You can accept this answer by clicking the check box to the left.